# date format within dataset column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, stringr

I have dataset, df, that has a column labeled date. I would like to change the format for all of the data within this date column.

```
  date

  29/11/2019 11:28:04 AM
  29/11/2019 11:28:05 AM
```

I would like for the column to look like this:

```
  date

  11/29/2019 11:28:04 AM
  11/29/2019 11:28:05 AM
```

Here is the dput:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("29/11/2019      11:28:04 AM", 
"29/11/2019 11:28:05 AM"), class = "factor")), class =    "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -2L))
```

This is what I have tried:

```
 newdate<- format(df$date("%m/%d/%Y" %H%m%s %d))
```

I realize I have the syntax wrong, I am researching this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `dmy_hms` to convert to `Datetime` and then wrap with `format`

```
library(lubridate)
format(dmy_hms(df$Date), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") 
#[1] "11/29/2019 11:28:04 AM" "11/29/2019 11:28:05 AM"
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `strptime` with `strftime`

```
strftime(strptime(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %T"),  "%m/%d/%Y %T")
#[1] "11/29/2019 11:28:04 AM" "11/29/2019 11:28:05 AM"
```

Comment: Hi @Akrun, all of the data was converted correctly, however, the other columns are not there. Can I preserve all the columns in my dataset and convert too?

Comment: @TanishaHudson. Just update with `df$Date <- format(dmy_hms..`

Comment: @TanishaHudson Did you meant that there are multiple columns to convert to date time or all columns

Comment: No @akrun I only have one date column, but the rest of the columns are like, subject, id, itemname, etc

Comment: Ok like this? df$date <- format(dmy_hms, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p") ?

Comment: @TanishaHudson Yes, but include `dmy_hms(df$Date)`

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can use `as.POSIXct` to convert to date-time and then use `format` to get data in required format.

```
format(as.POSIXct(df$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p"), "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
#[1] "11/29/2019 11:28:04 AM" "11/29/2019 11:28:05 AM"
```